# WP7 WebClient cannot find specific server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

Ok, maybe this is the dumbest question ever but I really can't understand what's happening :D

I have this simple code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri url = new Uri("http://www.something.com/");
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();  
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Result;
    }
```

It works well, except for one case (obviously the one that I need), when the address of the server is "ts4.travian.it". In this case I get this error: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
The strange thing is that if I write a small console application with basically the same code, it works...any idea?

EDIT: To be more specific, the server return error 403 - Forbidden, but if I try the same code in a Console Application, it works perfectly...don't know what to think..I'm debugging the application on a Nokia Lumia 800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem finally. The Silverlight framework automatically set the Referer header of the HttpWebRequest, and the server "ts4.travian.it" refused it because it was not correct.

Comment: Thank you for posting your resolution, as it just helped me fix a similar issue. Removing the `referer` header stopped me receiving a 403 response, and allowed the request to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to provide the output for that one case?

**Edit**:

Status code '**403**' implies that there' something the server doesn't like in your app. Who knows maybe it checks your UA string and sees that you're using IE Mobile i guess. Than he desides not to allow you see the content. Hm?

Comment: No, it returns an error "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Comment: Yeah. The thing is that this error description is not that helpful coz lots of web exceptions return "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
Silly question: aren't you trying to connect to "ts4.travian.it" and not "http://ts4.travian.it" with "http://" at the beginning ?

Comment: Instead of Uri url = new Uri("http://www.something.com/") I write Uri url = new Uri("http://ts4.travian.it/")

Comment: I also tried to change the user agent, no way...same result...in addiction to this, if I try to fetch another page (ts1.travian.com) the code works...

Comment: I'm almost sure that this is server-side issue. No can tell any useful without knowing what's happening there when app connects. Since that another page works well and it looks identical (i guess) why not to use it instead?

Comment: Because I wanted to create an app that works for every server of Travian, not only for one. Thanks anyway for your time and help...I'll try to figure it out somehow.